# Animating active (hovered) thumbnail opacity in a gallery with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover, opacity

I'm trying to animate the opacity. Default opacity is 0.8 for all thumbnails. Once hovered, the opacity increases to 1 and should go back to 0.8 when another thumbnail is hovered.

I've tried this code:

```
container.delegate("a:has(img)", "mouseenter", function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 1}, options.thumbsopacityFadeTime);
}).delegate("a:has(img)", "mouseout", function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).stop(false, true).animate({opacity: options.thumbsOpacity}, options.thumbsopacityFadeTime); 
);
```

but the hovered thumbnails sometimes (most of the time) goes back to the default opacity, even when the mouse is still over that same thumbnail and hasn't moved.

I assume this has something to do with the animations currently running and what not, but I thought $(e.currentTarget) would only apply to this 1 thumbnail, so why would a mouse out event be triggered for that thumbnail when I do not leave the thumbnail?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand you that you don't want to have mouseout effect? Only when hovering different thumbnail?

FIrst attempt should be replacing "mouseout" to "mouseleave". If it doesn't help, try different way:

```
var obj = container.find("a:has(img)");

obj.bind({
  mouseenter:function(){
    obj.stop().not(this).animate({opacity: options.thumbsopacity}, options.thumbsopacityFadeTime);
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, options.thumbsopacityFadeTime);
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
    // nothing :)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it was just mouseleave that I needed. DOH!